# ¿Como puedo ingresar los datos de un DataGridView a una tabla de SQL por medio de Linq?

Tags: sql, linq, datagrid

Tengo que llenar una tabla con los datos de un DataGridView pero no consigo hacerlo, paso los datos a un primer DataGriView. Todo esto con LINQ

[image: Filtro los datos de los controles al primer DataGriView]

Despues de llenar el primer DataGriView quiero que con el boton "Guardar Semana" se guarden los datos en SQQL y se muestrn en el segundo DataGriView (con mostrar no tengo problema). El codigo del boton es:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
DataGridView Grid = dataGridView1;
        for (int fila = 0; fila < Grid.Rows.Count - 1; fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < Grid.Rows[fila].Cells.Count; col++)
            {
                MenuporSemana ms = new MenuporSemana();                                        
                ms.Año = Convert.ToInt32(Grid.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
                ms.Semana = Convert.ToInt32(Grid.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
                ms.Dia = Grid.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
                ms.Sopa = Grid.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
                ms.Guisado = Grid.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
                Datos.MenuporSemana.InsertOnSubmit(ms);
                Datos.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
     }
```

Tambien habia intentado hacerlo con Foreach y lo tenia de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow GVRow in dataGridView1.Rows)

{
   MenuporSemana ms = new MenuporSemana();
   ms.Año = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
   ms.Semana = Convert.ToInt32(GVRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   ms.Dia = GVRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   ms.Sopa = GVRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
   ms.Guisado = GVRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
   Datos.MenuporSemana.InsertOnSubmit(ms);
   Datos.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Pero ninguna de las dos funciono y me gustaria saber como implementar esa parte o si es que hay otra forma para hacerlo. Gracias.